# why <a> tags with different classes are not independent?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

Here is my code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"> 
    <head>
    <style type="text/css"> 


        #holder {width:750px; height:350px; position:relative; font-family:arial, sans-serif; border-top:1px solid #da8; border-bottom:1px solid #da8; z-index:100;}
    #holder table {border-collapse:collapse; margin:-1px;}
    #holder ul {float:left; padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none;}
    #holder ul.sub {margin-bottom:-4px;}
    #menuOuter li a.lv1-a {background:blue; zoom:1;}
    #menuOuter li a.lv1-a:hover {direction:ltr;}

    #holder ul.sub {float:left;}
    #holder ul.sub ul {position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:180px;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a img {display:block; position:absolute; left:-9999px; border:0; height:200px; width:750px;}

    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li {display:block; float:left; width:150px; height:240px;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a {margin-top:200px; width:110px; display:block; padding:0 20px; height:40px; line-height:40px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-family:arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a1 {background:#e9a358;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a2 {background:#e9a358;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a3 {background:#9ea64b;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a4 {background:#dfb344;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a5 {background:#b8826e;}

    #menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current a {margin-top:200px; height:40px;}
    #menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current ul {left:-9999px;}
    #menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current a img {left:-9999px;}

    #menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a {margin-top:200px; height:40px;}
    #menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current ul {left:-9999px;}
    #menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a img {left:-9999px;}

    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover > a {margin-top:0; height:350px;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a:hover {margin-top:0; height:350px;}

    #holder ul.sub li.current a {margin-top:0; height:350px;
            top: 14px;
            left: 28px;
        }
    #holder ul.sub li.current a.a1 img {left:0; top:0; z-index:-1;}
    #holder ul.sub li.current a.a2 img {left:-150px; top:0; z-index:-1;}
    #holder ul.sub li.current a.a3 img {left:-300px; top:0; z-index:-1;}
    #holder ul.sub li.current a.a4 img {left:-450px; top:0; z-index:-1;}
    #holder ul.sub li.current a.a5 img {left:-600px; top:0; z-index:-1;}

    #menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current:hover a {margin-top:0; height:350px;}
    #menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current:hover ul {left:0;}
    #menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current:hover ul li {float:left; height:15px; padding:0; margin:0;}
    #menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current:hover ul li a {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px;}
    #menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current:hover ul li a:hover {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; text-decoration:underline;}

    #menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a:hover {margin-top:0; height:350px;}
    #menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a:hover ul {left:0;}
    #menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a:hover ul li {float:left; height:15px; padding:0; margin:0;}
    #menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a:hover ul li a {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px;}
    #menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a:hover ul li a:hover {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; text-decoration:underline;}


    #holder ul.sub li {position:relative;}

    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover ul {left:0; width:130px;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover ul li {float:left; height:15px; padding:0; margin:0;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover ul li a {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; font-size:11px;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover ul li a:hover {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; text-decoration:underline;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover a.a1 img {left:0; top:0; z-index:-1;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover a.a2 img {left:-150px; top:0; z-index:-1;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover a.a3 img {left:-300px; top:0; z-index:-1;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover a.a4 img {left:-450px; top:0; z-index:-1;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover a.a5 img {left:-600px; top:0; z-index:-1;}

    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a:hover ul {left:0; width:130px;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a:hover ul li {float:left; height:15px; padding:0; margin:0;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a:hover ul li a {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; font-size:11px;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a:hover ul li a:hover {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; text-decoration:underline;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a1:hover img {left:0; top:0; z-index:-1;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a2:hover img {left:-150px; top:0; z-index:-1;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a3:hover img {left:-300px; top:0; z-index:-1;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a4:hover img {left:-450px; top:0; z-index:-1;}
    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a5:hover img {left:-600px; top:0; z-index:-1;}

    #holder ul.sub li.current ul {left:0; width:130px;}
    #holder ul.sub li.current ul li {float:left; height:15px; padding:0; margin:0;}
    #holder ul.sub li.current ul li a {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; font-size:11px;}

    #holder ul.sub li span {display:block;position:absolute; top:240px; left:0; line-height:15px; width:130px; padding:10px; height:90px; z-index:-1; color:#000; text-decoration:none; font-size:11px;}
    #holder ul.sub li.p1 span {background:#ffe398;}
    #holder ul.sub li.p2 span {background:#ffe398;}
    #holder ul.sub li.p3 span {background:#dee68b;}
    #holder ul.sub li.p4 span {background:#fff384;}
    #holder ul.sub li.p5 span {background:#f8c2ae;}

    #holder ul.sub li.sub-li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 240px;
        width: 150px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------*/
    #slider img {
            border-style: none;
                border-color: inherit;
                border-width: medium;
                position:absolute;
                visibility:hidden;
                top: 4px;
                left: -4px;
                height: 315px;
                width: 729px;

            }
            /*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
            /* ----------- thumbnails ----------- */
    #thumbs 
    {
        background:white url(thumbs-bar.gif) repeat-x 0 0; 
        border:1px solid white; text-align:center; 
        font-size:0px;
        line-height:45px;/*Setting the expected height to line-height fixes many IE8 erratic behaviours*/
        position:fixed;
            top: 184px;
            left: 378px;
            width: 22px;
            height: 18px;
            bottom: 325px;
        }
    #thumbs .thumb 
    {
        width:60px;height:45px;
        cursor:pointer;
        text-align:center;
        border-left:1px solid #FFF; border-right:1px solid #DDD; 

        display:inline-block;
        *display:inline;zoom:1; /*IE Hack*/
    }
    #thumbs .thumb-on {background-image: url(active-bg.png);}
    #thumbs .thumb img {vertical-align:middle;}


            /* ----------- navigation buttons in the thumbnails bar ---------- */
    a.group2-Play, a.group2-Pause 
    {
         width:20px; height:20px; 
        background:transparent url(navButtons.gif); 
        display:inline-block; 
        *display:inline;zoom:1;/*IE hack*/
        margin-right:8px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    a.group2-Pause{background-position:0 0;

        }
    a.group2-Play {background-position:0 -20px;
           }


    a.group2-Pause:hover{background-position:20px 0;}
    a.group2-Play:hover {background-position:20px -20px;}





    </style> 

    </head>
```

these were css classes.

```
 <body id="www-cssplay-co-uk" class="menus"> 


    <div id="holder"> 
    <ul id="menuOuter"> 
        <li class="lv1-li"> 
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><a class="lv1-a" href="#url1"><table><tr><td><![endif]--> 
            <ul class="sub" id="d"> 
                <li class="sub-li p1 current"  href="#url"><a  class="a1" href="" >
                   <div id="slider" style="position:fixed; width:750px; height:200px; background-color:white; top: 9px; left: 12px; z-index:-1; background:transparent url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;">
                        <img src="a2.jpg"  /> 
                        <img src="slider-2.jpg"  /> 
                        <img src="slider-3.jpg"  />
                        <img src="slider-4.jpg"  /> 
                   </div>
                    <div id="thumbs"> 

                      <a onclick="switchAutoAdvance()" id='auto' class="group2-Pause"></a>


                    </div>

                   <b>guest room</b><!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]--> 
                <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]--> 
                    <ul> 
                        <li><a href="#url">1</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#url">2</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#url">3</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#url">4</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#url">5</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#url">6</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#url">7</a></li> 
                    </ul> 
                    <span>explainations</span> 
                <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--> 
                </li> 

                <li class="sub-li p5"><a class="a5" href="#url"><img src="pic5.jpg" /><b>baby room</b><!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]--> 
                <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]--> 
                    <ul> 
                        <li><a href="#url">Sleep Suits</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#url">//</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#url">//</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#url">//</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#url">//</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#url">//</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#url">//</a></li> 
                    </ul> 
                    <span>//</span> 
                <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--> 
                </li> 
            </ul>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--> 

    ​
    </li> 
    </ul> 
    </div> 
     <script type="text/javascript">
         amenu.open("v_is", true);

         //The following script is for the group 2 navigation buttons.
         function switchAutoAdvance() {
             imageSlider.switchAuto();
             switchPlayPauseClass();
         }
         function switchPlayPauseClass() {
             var auto = document.getElementById('auto');
             var isAutoPlay = imageSlider.getAuto();
             auto.className = isAutoPlay ? "group2-Pause" : "group2-Play";
             auto.title = isAutoPlay ? "Pause" : "Play";
         }
         switchPlayPauseClass();

         //take tm1 out of the div.main
         function dm1() {
             var dm1 = document.getElementById("dm1");
             //var main = document.getElementById("main");
             //main.parentNode.appendChild(dm1);
             document.body.appendChild(dm1);
         }
         dm1();
        </script> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

and this is my hovering menu,'auto' anchor tag is a stop button for my slideshow,but I cant place it in its right place,and change its size because when tring to make differences in its size other anchor tags also change although every anchor tag has its own class.although anchor tags have their own classes but they are not independent,when I change the size of 'auto' anchor tag,other anchor tags size also change,how can I make the anchor tags independent?and my other problem is that although 'auto' anchor tag is defined in 'thumbs' division but it doesn't stay in the division and places out of it or is bigger than it.

Comment: You need to clean this up a lot. You've got way too much stuff going on here. Trim down your code to only the relevant pieces, and please clarify exactly what you're seeing compared to what you're expecting or need.

Comment: I echo what @JoeEnos said; while I *think* I can identify the code you are talking about, it doesn't obviously seem to be able to cause what you describe, so I can't be sure. Please narrow your code sample down to those parts which are directly relevant to changing the size(s) of your `<a>` tag(s).

Comment: Also try improving the readability of your question. End sentences occasionally. Break them up into paragraphs. Use spaces and capitalization. You're asking people to put effort into your answer, so put a little into your question.